# Is it possible to create a table that updates its contents from a view once a day?

Tags: sql, oracle

Given that the view collects a large amount of data and it would reduce the server's performance if it is run too frequently. Is it possible to create a sort of table that takes the results from that view and some sort of scheduling for it to do it once a day? So that any other queries take the information from this table and not from the view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be a materialised view, which may be regarded as a combination of:

- A predefined query
- A table for storing the results of that query
- Metadata concerning the frequency and type of refresh to which it is subject
- Metadata concerning other items, such as whether queries against objects that its own query references may be rewritten to address the materialised view if that it calculated to be more efficient.

They are also used for some forms of replication.

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10706/repmview.htm#REPLN265 and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/basicmv.htm#DWHSG0081